# run node.js server for chat app in e-commerce website

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, html, apache

I want to add a chat app to my e-commerce website which offers one-to-one chat between the buyers and the sellers. After searching ,web sockets seems to be right for this but it requires node.js server and the rest of my website is in php with apache server. 
I have read that it is not good to run both apache and node server at the same time. For video chat I'm using [appear.in](https://appear.in/)'s javascript api which has no such limitations.
How can I run the node.js app under this scenario?

Comment: Downvoted and flagged because the question is asking for recommendations on services, Please read the how to ask section for proper question format.

Comment: Using websockets does not require node.js server. Many webservers offer websocket support. I am not sure whether Apache offers it.

In any case, if your question is solely about webservers to give websockets support it might be better suited on ServerFault. If your question is about how to create a chat program with websockets, please google for a tutorial yourself, StackOverflow is not the right place.

See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of web socket libraries for PHP, e.g. [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/).

If this is the only reason for you to move parts of you application to Node.js, you shouldn't necessarily do it.